# Shell script that writes in grunt shell?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to write a shell script that opens grunt shell, runs a pig file in it and then copies the output files to local machine. Is this possible? Any links will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you can run a pig script from the command line:

```
#> pig -f script.txt
```

The tail end of the script can execute fs commands to 'get' the data back to the local filesystem

```
grunt> fs -get /path/in/hdfs /local/path
```